# How I can modularize Rails model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm implementing several classes which does not have data by itself, just logics. These classes implements access control policy to date which depends on several parameters taken from data from other models.

I initially try to find answer to "Where to store such classes?" here, and the answer was `apps/models` directory. That's ok, but I like to clearly separate these classes from ActiveRecord inherited classes in hierarchy, both as file and class.

So, I created classes inside `Logic` module, like `Logic::EvaluationLogic` or `Logic::PhaseLogic`. I also wanted to have constants which passed between these logics. I prefer to place these constants into `Logic` module too. Thus, I implemented like this:

```
# in logic/phase_logic.rb
module Logic
  PHASE_INITIAL = 0
  PHASE_MIDDLE  = 1000

  class PhaseLogic
    def self.some_phase_control_code
    end
  end
end

# in logic/evaluation_logic.rb
module Logic
  class EvaluationLogic
    def self.some_other_code
      Logic::PhaseLogic.self.some_phase_control_code(Logic::PHASE_INITIAL)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, it work just fine with `rspec` (It passes tests I wrote without issues), but not with development server, since it can't find the `Logic::PHASE_INITIAL` constant.

I suspect it's related to the mismatch of the autoloading scheme of Rails and what I wanted to do. I tried to tweak rails, but no luck, ended-up with eliminating `module Logic` wrap.

Now the question I want to ask: How I can organize these classes with Rails?
I'm using 3.2.1 at this moment.

**Posted a follow-up question "[How I can organize namespace of classes in app/modules with rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712468/how-i-can-organize-namespace-of-classes-in-app-modules-with-rails)"**

Comment: perhaps in `lib/logic/` and include/extend in the pertinent models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I really understand your classes, but couldn't you create a `Logic` module or *(I would rather do this:)* `PhaseLogic` and `EvaluationLogic` objects **in `/lib` directory**?

It is not said that "Model" is always descendant of ActiveRecord. If the object belongs to "business logic" then it is a model. You can have models which do not touch database in any way. So, if your classes are "business objects", place them in 'app/models' and use like any other model.

Another question is whether you should use **inheritance or modules** - but I would rather think about including a module in `PhaseLogic`, and not about defining `PhaseLogic` in a module. Of course, all this depends heavily on the intended role of your objects.

Because in Ruby the class of object is not important, you do not need to use inheritance. If you want to 'plug' the logic objects into other objects, just take care that all '*Logic' classes have the required methods. I know that all I said is very vague, but I think I cannot give you some more concrete suggestions without knowing more about the role of these objects.

Ah, and one more thing!

If you find yourself fighting with Rails class autoloading, just use the old `require "lib/logic.rb"` in all the classes where you are using `Logic::PHASE_INITIAL` constants.

In this case I suppose that your problem was caused by different order of loading. The `logic/evaluation_logic.rb` has been loaded before `logic/phase_logic.rb`. The problem may disappear if you create `logic.rb` somewhere, where class autoloading can find it, and define these constants in that file.

Comment: You could also use `config.autoload_paths += "#{config.root}/wherever_you_want_to_put_your_logic_classes"` in `config/application.rb` to not have to use `require` at all.

Comment: I realized that I mixed two questions into one.

My initial thought was placing such class into `lib` like you suggested. But I thought somewhat awkward to place such thing into `lib`. I tried to find recommendation in Stackoverflow, and found that majority of people suggest to place into `models`.

How to design the classes are different issue, and I haven't described well enough why I took the course. My intention was I want to implement two type of logics which interact, so put them into single namespace seems reasonable, so above structure. (con't)

Comment: And style of use of modules, I prefer to my scheme for this purpose, since I want to encapsulate the logics into the class and don't want to pollute the class which refer to the module (by including it). This is partially because I'm still not used to ruby's way of mix-in (I'm using C++ too long: 20+ years)

Also note that, as Frost recommended, using autoload_paths for outside of `app` seems natural. I can solve with this scheme, but I will post another question to see.

-- thanks anyway for answer/comments

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your classes or modules `Logic` use specific names. Start with extracting logic into separate classes and then try to break them into smaller ones. Use namespaces to distinguish them from each other in `lib` folder, after this steps you would be able to extract some logic parts to separate gems and reduce codebase and complexity of application. Also take a look into [presenter](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/simplifying-your-ruby-on-rails-code/) pattern.

Comment: I'm using `module` for namespace separation. How do you differentiate namespaces other than `module`?