# How I can organize namespace of classes in app/modules with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

*[This is a follow-up question to "[How I can modularize Rails model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701947/how-i-can-modularize-rails-model)"]*

Is there anyway to organize classes in `app/models` directory of Rails?
Do I have to use single top-level namespace for all of the classes?

Initial motivation is, I want place business logic classes which do not inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` into `app/models` directory. Searching this site reveals many answers which recommend to place business logics classes in the `app/models` directory. I posted [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701947/how-i-can-modularize-rails-model), and got recommendation that it is possible to place such classes into `lib` directory.

Now I'm curious. I'd like to place these classes into different namespace and directory in `apps/models` directory which recommended by others. Is it possible?

Actually, I experiment that, but it seems to me that is what rails is not expected. If I create such a class (like SomeModName::ClassInMod in some_mod_name/class_in_mod.rb ) it does not get loaded. Also, I defined constants inside the module. Since they're not loaded, I can't use them. Actually, with `rspec` it work without problem, but with `rails server`, the class does not loaded. I'm sure it is related to autoloading issue.

In addition to the classes mentioned above, classes inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` can be placed into some namespaces inside a `module`. I'm curious whether this work well or not too.

So the question in other words: can I make rails happy by configuring these files to be loaded, or is not the way rails designed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you can** define an ActiveRecord class in a module. The easy way is to use the generator:

```
./script/rails generate model logic/phase_logic
./script/rails generate model logic/evaluation_logic
```

Observe, that Rails will create additionally a file with the definition of the module. In this case:

```
# app/models/logic.rb
module Logic
  ...
end

# app/models/logic/phase_logics.rb
class Logic::PhaseLogic < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# app/models/logic/evaluation_logics.rb
class Logic::EvaluationLogic < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Your problems with constants defined in the module were caused by the fact, that you defined the constants in the definition module "wrapped" around only one model, from the two you have created. A very important part in understanding ruby (and Rails) - *especially for people who have strong background in compiled languages* - is to remember that **there is no compilation phase**, so the definition of some class is read and executed only when that specific class is used. Sometimes **a week** after the application server has been started and served thousands of requests.

Thus, as I said in the [previous question](/questions/9701947/how-i-can-modularize-rails-model)'s answer, the problem with autoloading was that sometimes the definition of the constants was read *after* the definition which was trying to use them. The order was random - if the first used object happened to be EvaluationLogic, then the error emerged. It the first object happened to be PhaseLogic, everything was fine.

Now, when you have a file for the module itself, and **define constants in that file** (`app/models/logic.rb`), autoloading will be able to find and execute the definitions before any class starts to use them. I hope everything will be OK.

Comment: Thanks. I still want to figure out why load order is different from what I expected (you said this is random, I think there must be a trigger that cause the actual load), but it is clearly good idea to place constant to `app/models/logic.rb` will try change this way now.

Comment: Tested. It's not even necessary to be a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` Placed all constants in `module Logic`, placing it in `app/models/logic.rb` solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: The actual load is triggered by the first executed line of code, where the class is used. When ruby tries to execute something like `if false; EvaluationLogic.new; else PhaseLogic.new; end` and PhaseLogic is not yet defined, then (simplifying things a little) autoloading mechanism finds the file `phase_logic.rb`, executes it, and tries to execute that line of code again. There are also other ways like STI.

Comment: And you are right - autoloading does not care whether the object is ActiveRecord or not. It works for every undefined class/constant.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know any documentation describing that?

Comment: I have learned most things from browsing the Rails' sources, but that was way back in version 1.x, when the code was smaller and easier to understand _(the main concepts haven't changed that much)_. That page looks sensible, though: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:n9F8HGnmI3gJ:wondible.com/2011/12/23/give-rails-autoloading-a-boot-to-the-head/&strip=1