# What's a good technique for naming Rails models to avoid conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do *you* reliably name your classes in Rails?

There doesn't seem to be a reliable nor current list of Rails reserved words online, and many obvious choices for model names seem to be taken.

My back story:

I added a new class to handle file attachments and named this class `Files`. This caused much grief. I renamed it `Assets` and should have guessed Rails wouldn't route correctly. Next came `Media`, which seemed obscure and safe, but postgres stopped joining tables. Then it was `Attachments` but Paperclip stopped returning the correct attribute values. It's a lot of work to rename a class by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your models in a module so that it creates a namespace around your models.

Its been explained here :[How I can organize namespace of classes in app/modules with rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712468/how-i-can-organize-namespace-of-classes-in-app-modules-with-rails)