# Rails create! using wrong class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models `Plan` and `Student::Plan`. When calling `Student::Plan.create!` in my seeds.rb file I get back a `Plan` object. It seems as though rails is getting confused by the namespacing or something. Any thoughts that don't involve renaming the class?

**file structure**

```
models
  plan.rb
  student
    plan.rb
```

**tables**

- plans
- student_plans

**Update**

This gets even weirder when testing w/ `rails c`. If you call `Student::Plan.create!` **first** then you'll get the expected object back. If you instead call `Plan.create!` and then `Student::Plan.create!` you'll be back a `Plan` object instead of what you'd actually expect.

### Works

```
Student::Plan.create # <Student::Plan...>
```

### Doesn't Work

```
Plan.create # <Plan...>
Student::Plan.create # <Plan...>
```

Comment: Where did you place `Student::Plan`?

Comment: @KenrickChien I've updated w/ some additional details

Comment: Does `Student::Plan` inherit from `Plan`? Are you referencing `Plan` within the `Student` module before `Student::Plan` is properly loaded? Calling these both `Plan` is trouble.

Comment: It seems like you're getting problems from Rails' autoloading of classes.  Some possible solutions:

1. Move `Student::Plan` to lib.
2. place `require 'student/plan'` where you need to reference `Student::Plan`.

Comment: @tadman No it doesn't inherit from it

Comment: @KyleDecot If you called it `Plan::StudentPlan` instead it would probably work as expected.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it belongs in `lib` as it's an `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

Comment: @tadman Yes this would probably work but naming that wouldn't make any sense as the two models are completely unrelated to each other (aside from their unfortunate naming).

Comment: Doesn't this seem like a bug? The autoloader should know how to handle models of the same name where one is namespaced (isn't the entire purpose of namespacing to allow for classes of the same name?).

Comment: You may need `models/student.rb` to define `module Student` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712468/how-i-can-organize-namespace-of-classes-in-app-modules-with-rails and http://wondible.com/2011/12/23/give-rails-autoloading-a-boot-to-the-head/

Comment: Have you actually namespaced the class beyond placing it in the directory structure? The behaviour you describe doesn't happen when I replicate this exact example.

Comment: @MikeCampbell yes I have. I'm using rails 4.0.0RC1. I'm not sure if it's specific to that version or not.

Comment: what's your table set up? is your table namespaced?

Comment: @MikeCampbell I've updated my post w/ the tables

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't have a student_plan.rb at the root of the models directory?

Comment: https://github.com/mikecmpbll/namespace_test - works for me, figure out what's different and you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a scenario where you have namespaced models (I've used it a few times...usually for integrating different db's). And this answer doesn't get to the issue of dealing with namespacing issues, but I do think the "Judo" solution is to just create a model called `student_plan.rb` at the root of the models directory, and use `StudentPlan.create` and `Plan.create` respectively.